# Complex System Of Equations To Define Geometry For Hanging Plotter

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems, computer-algebra-systems

I have a relatively simple geometric system which is proving exceptionally difficult to solve. Any advice on how to proceed is much appreciated.

[image: Illustration Of Geometry]

I know the coordinates of three points on a 2D plane A,B,C.

I need to find the the points D,E,F,G such that E and G lie on the lines AD and GD respectively and F is the midpoint of EG and is on the line CD. ED and DG are of equal length.

The lengths of AB, FC and EG are known. AB = 2950, FC = 300, EG = 130

The true objective of solving the problem is to simulate a hanging plotter where the pen is not anchored at the middle of the two strings, but is instead held at points E and G. AE and BG are steel cables, while the assembly made up of EFGC is made of wood. Most hanging plotters suffer from this issue, but it has historically been ignored in the designs because they are small enough that the error is not an issue and only operate well below the motors. Again, any advice at all is appreciated.

[Machine Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZwB.png)

Thank you.

Comment: The strings $ED$ and $DG$ do nothing. The orientation of the stiff head (points $CDEFG$) depends on the mass distribution in it. If all mass was in point $C$, then $CDF$ would always be vertical. You could solve the orientation issue by adding a rod, hinged at the top, along which the head assembly could move (up and down), but always keep a radial orientation with respect to the hinge. Then again, you could also solve it by adding a third string down, with the stiff head being an equilateral triangle. That would work even horizontally, if you added three omnidirectional castors.

Comment: For a better two-string model, you'd need at least the mass of the stiff head, the approximate mass of the string (per length unit), and the location of the center of mass in the stiff head. Even then it would be approximate. I do not think the current approximations in hanging plotters are because *the math* is hard -- it isn't --, but because it is so darned annoying to get the details needed to match a proper physics model to a real device.

Comment: Thank you for responding @NominalAnimal ! My situation is a little different than the standard hanging plotter problem in that I am operating in the region close to the top where the tension in the ropes (steel cables in  my case) is very large relative to the mass of the pen making the mass effects negligible. I have shown experimentally that the system behaves as described in the above diagram, but the math eludes me

Comment: Even using fixed-length sticks as $AE$ and $BG$ does not fix the location of $C$ with respect to $EG$. You can verify this by setting $AE$ and $BG$ to some known lengths, but adding a mass point (say, a small lead weight) somewhere along the $FC$ line. You'll see that that added mass changes the location of $C$ with respect to $EG$. Because we do not know the mass distribution of your actual head assembly, we cannot model it properly. We can make guesses, but that's what others do and have done already. Are you willing to measure your head assembly, if given instructions?

Comment: Thank you for making the picture appear. I don't have the reputation to do that. I have added another image to be more clear $AE$ and $BG$ are the steel cables and the location of $C$ is fixed in relation to $EG$ because they are all part of the same construction. You are 100% correct that changing the center of mass of the head assembly will change the way it hangs but the far more dominant effect is for the head to align with the steel cables because the tension is so great. I am happy to measure anything about the head assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a left-handed coordinate system, where the origin is at the midway between points
$$A = \left ( -\frac{L}{2}, 0 \right ) \; \text{ and } \; B = \left ( +\frac{L}{2}, 0 \right)$$
making their distance $L$, $x$ increasing right, and $y$ down; assume $y \ge 0$.

---

In the classic three-point assembly, we only have $A$, $B$, and $D$.

Let's use $r_A$ for the cable length from $A$ to $D$, and $r_B$ for the cable length from $B$ to $D$, and $D = (x,y)$, we have two equations,
$$\begin{cases}
\left(x + \frac{L}{2}\right)^2 + y^2 = r_A^2 \\
\left(x - \frac{L}{2}\right)^2 + y^2 = r_B^2
\end{cases}$$
Solving those for $x$ and $y$ yields
$$\begin{cases}
x = \frac{r_A^2 - r_B^2}{2 L} \\
y = \frac{\sqrt{-(L+r_A+r_B)(L+r_A-r_B)(L-r_A+r_B)(L-r_A-r_B)}}{2 L}
\end{cases}$$
and solving for $r_A$ and $r_B$ yields
$$\begin{cases}
r_A = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}L^2 + L x + x^2 + y^2 } \\
r_B = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}L^2 - L x + x^2 + y^2 }
\end{cases}$$

---

If we have cables from $A$ to $E$ (length $r_E$), and from $B$ to $G$ (length $r_G$), with $CDEFG$ being a rigid piece, we can no longer rely on the simple math.

If we use $E = (x_E, y_E)$ and $G = (x_G, y_G)$, with $d$ being the distance between $E$ and $G$, we have three equations
$$\begin{cases}
\left(x_E + \frac{L}{2}\right)^2 + y_E^2 = r_E^2 \\
\left(x_G - \frac{L}{2}\right)^2 + y_G^2 = r_G^2 \\
(x_G - x_E)^2 + (y_G - y_E)^2 = d^2
\end{cases}$$
but we have four unknowns: the remaining degree of freedom being the orientation of the $CDEFG$ part.

If we look at the situation from a physics point of view, gravity is no longer a simple force that pulls $D$ down like it is in the simple $ABD$ case (ignoring inertia and momentum; say, slow movement and friction and friction-like losses making them neglible).

In this case, we also have [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) due to gravity. The location of the center of mass relative to $E$ and $G$ means gravity does not just pull the assembly down; it tends to turn it, too.

Furthermore, the steel cables have considerable weight compared to the had assembly $CDEFG$. Even while taut, they are not straight; there is some curvature. In practice, the steel cables' weight is also part of the assembly, affecting both the mass distribution, as well as the torque (pulling the assembly off from vertical).

If you know

- the weight of the fixed assembly $CDEFG$
- the steel cable weight per length unit
- the distance between $E$ and $G$
- the distance from $E$ and $G$ to the center of mass, with steel cables not attached (to $E$ and $G$)

  (the center of mass can be found using a pin: if the pin is in the correct location, holding the assembly in the air, the assembly should not tip)

then it should be possible to physically model the situation. The math is hairy (just thinking about the integrals for the cables gives me the jeebies), and the model being quite nonlinear, will likely not allow a simple algebraic solution for $(x,y)$ or $(r_1, r_2)$.

Personally, I think it might be easier to model the physics directly in the microcontroller, with iterative controls. (At any time step, one can do one of nine things -- nothing, shorten or lengthen $AE$, or shorten or lengthen $BG$ --; calculating the effects of each, and picking the one that yields the results most desirable, should work.)

It might look funny, though. Similar control loops occasionally produce counterintuitive effects. Oscillation is a problem, so you'd probably need to model the movement of the head down to third derivatives (for both location and orientation).

---

Physically, the device can be trivially augmented to avoid the orientation problem.

For example, consider the $CDF$ part being replaced with a long rod, long enough to always intersect $AB$. At the midpoint of $AB$, a freely rotating bushing -- one that both rotates, but also allows the rod to move within linearly -- would fix the angle, making the math easy again.

I myself have played with a circular/rotary design. The frame is a circle, with a timing belt running on the outside. It is held in place by three rubber wheels. A stepper motor on the belt controls the rotation of the circular frame. The pen/head assembly moves in a linear slot in the center of the frame, also using a timing belt. The setup works both horizontally and vertically. The frame, two timing belts and pulleys, three outer wheels, and one freewheeling pulley are additional costs compared to the original minimal string-based hanging plotter, but not by that much: roughly 10-20 USD or EUR in late 2016.

---

Defining $E$ and $G$ using $F$ (at distance $d/2$ at angles $\varphi$ and $\varphi+180°$) yields two pairs of expressions for the coordinates of $F$ as a function of $\varphi$ using the three equations mentioned above, but they have a few dozen terms each.

If we assume the physics and geometry to be such that $\angle AEG = \angle EGB$, we get an additional equation,
$$\frac{\vec{EA}\cdot\vec{EG}}{d r_E} = \frac{\vec{GE}\cdot\vec{GB}}{d r_G}$$
Solving the four equations for the coordinates of $E$ and $G$ yields a tangle of solutions. For example, there are three solutions for $r_E$, one of which is sane, but two have thousands of terms.

Comment: What a gorgeous answer! You say, "but we have four unknowns: the remaining degree of freedom being the orientation of the $CDEFG$ part." That is right, BUT in the case where the center of gravity is near the center and the cable tension is much larger than the torsional force the line $FC$ will bisect the angle $ADB$ constraining that extra degree of freedom. This is assuming that the weight of the cables is minimal, weight is all concentrated at the center, sliding friction is zero. Experimentally I've seen that this is nearly the case, I just can't solve the math problem making it work

Comment: @BarSmith: If I understood you correctly, we could assume the properties of the device are such that $\angle AEF = \angle FGB$. That should suffice; let me see if I can formulate it in an useful way. (I wonder if making $EDG$ a half-circle arc, connecting both at $D$ only, would help with that.)

Comment: That is a very interesting point. I hadn't considered that. I instinctively think that you are correct, but I don't have proof to back that up

Comment: I think that I've phrased this question poorly and that you have really answered the question I originally asked. Rather than heavily editing my question to reflect what I meant to ask I'd like to accept your answer and make a new question which is strictly about the geometry. Is that OK with you?

Comment: That is perfectly fine. You do not need to accept my answer, either. (I only wish I knew why someone downvoted this answer.) Note that I did add a short addendum on two approaches; using $F$ as a focus point and leaving the rotation $\varphi$ from horizontal as a free variable yields two pairs of coordinates, each coordinate requiring dozens of terms (thus not likely reversible for getting cable lengths from $(x,y)$); the $\angle AEF = \angle FGB$ approach using vector dot product (essentially, $\cos(\angle AEF) = \cos(\angle FGB)$) yields expressions with thousands of terms.

Comment: If you could add a (static acceleration) sensor to measure the angle $EFG$ has compared to horizontal, it could be used to solve the math. (It wouldn't even need to know which way it is tilted, as that can be guessed from the cable lengths anyway; assuming the head assembly is symmetric wrt. $FDC$ line.) Something like a triple axis MEMS sensor should do fine; Adafruit ones start at 8 USD, Sparkfun at 15 USD, if I looked correctly, just check that they support static acceleration AKA tilt sensing.

Comment: You are right about the tangle of solutions. The concentric circles approach that someone posted to my related question is the slickest I've found so far, but it's still a mess. Thanks again for all your help.